# run cucumber tests parallel using cucumber-jvm 4

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

Java v8.x - spring v5.x cucumber v4.2.0

i tried `temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin` and it works fine, but when i get to their gitihub page they announced to stop using this plugin b/c cucumber already have start supporting parallel test running support from cucumber-jvm 4.0.0.

I have existing tests with using following maven dependencies.

```
cucumber-java v4.2.0
cucumber-junit v4.2.0
cucumber-spring v4.2.0
```

i have two questions making me confuse.

1. In order to use cucumber-jvm do i have to change my dependencies or my current dependencies will work.
2. can i start parallel cucumber tests just passing a parameter --parallel ?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parallel support was introduced in `cucumber-jvm:4.0.0`. So your dependencies are ok.

If you are using Maven:

> [Cucumber JUnit - Parallel Execution with Maven](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/v4.0.0/junit)
>
> Cucumber JUnit supports parallel execution of feature files across multiple threads. To enable this with maven set the parallel property to either `methods` or `both`.
>
> ```
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>             <configuration>
>                 <parallel>both</parallel>
>                 <threadCount>4</threadCount>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> ```

If you are using Gralde you are better off using the Gradle Cucumber Plugin as Gradle doesn't support sub-class level parallelization. In this case you don't need `cucumber-junit`.

> [Gradle Cucumber runner - Running features in parallel](https://github.com/tsundberg/gradle-cucumber-runner)
>
> Cucumber supports parallel execution if you specify the number of
>   thread to use. This can be done in two ways
>
> - An option whn running from a command line, `./gradlew cucumber --threads 4`, this will run four parallel threads
> - An extension, that is setting the value in your `build.gradle` file in the cucumber section.
>
> When setting the value in the build script, you can't really know how
>   many threads the build will have access to. Hardcoding a fixed number
>   may not be your best option.
>
> One way of specifying the number of threads to use is:
>
> ```
> cucumber {
>     threads = = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1 
> }
> ```
>
> This will use as many threads as possible while leaving resources for
>   Gradle to execute.

Comment: hi @mpkorstanje - Does same configure true for cucumber with testng we well?

Comment: Also, do we have any document with example sample for maven builds